# When designing a Python API, is it more Pythonic to throw exceptions or return false/None, etc?

Tags: python, api, exception, class-design

I am using a Python based API where there are lots of functions to query things, like `doesPointExist`, `findPoint`, `canCreateNewPoint`, etc where the negative result throws an exception. This makes the code much more cluttered filled with try/catch statements, instead of directly using the result as a boolean value.

Since I am not a Python expert, I am wondering if this design is Pythonic or not? I haven't seen this sort of design in the standard libraries though, so I am assuming this kind of exception usage in Python APIs is frowned upon?

Comment: It's generally more pythonic to use exceptions rather than checking return codes. [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

API design is a bit of an art. The name of a function should suggest how it will behave, including setting up user expectations. A function named `findPoint` implies that the search may fail, so the case where no such point exists is not exceptional, and may return `None` to signal the result. A function named `getPoint`, however, would imply to me that it can always return the requested point. A failure would be unexpected and warrant raising an exception.

Comment: Totally with you on the first two sentences. These two sentences are what is really missing from Simeon Visser's answer. Unfortunately, I don't think you picked the best examples. `getPoint` in particular reminds of `dict.get`, whose *sole purpose* is to ensure you don't get an exception. That said, I understand where you're going with that example. To me, `get` is intrinsically more ambiguous. I would have focused on slam-dunk cases: `doesPointExist` clearly should not raise just because point does not exist! The function's name is a question! You want an answer. The answer might be no.

Comment: I left out discussion of `doesPointExist` since Simeon Visser covered that aspect well. I actually intended this answer as more of an expansion of his answer, as this felt too long for a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a badly designed API.

- The function `doesPointExist` should return `True` or `False`, it shouldn't raise an exception when the point doesn't exist.
- The function `findPoint` should return a `Point` object or `None` when no object could be found.
- The function `canCreateNewPoint` should return `True` or `False` for similar reasons.

Exceptions are for exceptional cases.

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree that you won't find this in the standard library. For example, `"abc".index("d")` raises `ValueError`, lots of libraries raise exceptions freely.

I'd say it depends on what the consequences of a failed action are.

- If the caller can work with the returned value without change, I'd return an empty value (or `False`, if it's a yes or no question).
- If the call fails, I'd raise an exception. For example `findPoint()` might do that if it normally returns a `Point` object that the caller wants to work with.

Answer (score 2):

1, I would recommend to use exception for very specific cases, so you do not need to test for them in common situations.

2, You should read guidelines [PEP8 Naming Conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) regarding the names of your functions.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't unique to Python. The other answers are good, but just some additional thoughts that didn't fit well into a comment:

- You use exceptions when you don't want (or need) to check for the result. In this mode, you just do it, and if there's an error somewhere, you throw an exception. Getting rid of the explicit checks makes for shorter code, and you still get good debugging information when you DO get an exception, so it's common. This is the EAFP (easier to ask forgiveness than permission) style above.
- You use return codes when you do want to check for the result. Explicit checking is sometimes necessary if failures won't always fail cleanly, or to aid debugging in complex code flows. This is sometimes called the LBYL (look before you leap) style.

In Python, like most interpreted languages, because the overhead is so high, exceptions are relatively cheap, so it's much more common to use EAFP in Python than, say, C++ where the overhead is lower and exceptions are (relatively) more expensive.

Note that a function might both give a return value *and* possibly throw an exception.

In your example, a function like `doesPointExist` implies that the user is actually wanting to verify access before trying something. This is LBYL. Throwing an exception as a result value is part of the EAFP programming style, and wouldn't make sense for this function - if you wanted that style, you wouldn't check, you would just do it, and catch the exception when the point didn't exist.

However, even here there are assumptions - that you've given a valid point. It would be fine for the function to return True/False for whether the point exists, while throwing an exception if something that wasn't a point was passed to it.